# Mutual Information of Vectors with Large Inner Product

Tags: probability-theory, inner-products, information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

If we have a joint distribution of two (complex) vectors $x,y\in \mathbb{C}^d$ of norm $1$ such that their inner product $\langle x|y\rangle$ is $1-\epsilon$, can we lower bound the mutual information between $x$ and $y$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where does the problem come from?

Comment: If there is a joint distribution involved, by definition the inner product is also *random* so your question does not make sense without further explanation

Comment: @kodlu The question is if we know (x,y) are a joint distribution over x,y such that <x|y>=1-epsilon, can we lower bound the mutual information between x and y using this?

Comment: can you give an example [in the body of the question] of such a joint distribution which gives a fixed inner product?

Answer (score 1):

In general no. Let $X$ be a discrete random variable whose distribution's support is  $\{\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\}^d$. Then, define a new random variable $Y= (1-\epsilon)X + (1-(1-\epsilon)^2) X_{\perp}$ where $X_{\perp}$ is a norm-one vector orthogonal to $X$. It is easy to see that $<X,Y>=(1-\epsilon)$ with probability one. However, since $Y$ is a deterministic function of $X$, $I(X;Y)=0$.

Comment: Well the question says "of norm 1" so that doesn't quite work. But you can, e.g., just fix an appropriate rotation and hit $X$ with it.

Comment: fixed it. thanks!